# What does an empty # mean in a macro definition?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have the following macro:

```
#define F(Args, ...) \
   // macro definition
#
   F(()) // looks like usage?
#undef F
```

What does the line containing only `#` mean? Is `F(())` a usage of the macro?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Technically, that's not part of the macro (no continuation line before it).
It's a directive that comes after the `#define` directive.

`#` on its own line is called a [null directive](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.7) and it does nothing (as good as a comment).

It's no longer practically useful (except as a visual marker) but in prehistoric C, the preprocessor only got invoked if a C source file started with a directive and the null directive placed at the very beginning of a C file was a good way to make sure the file was preprocessed (i.e., that later directives worked) without starting with a concrete directive.

Comment: I suppose it can be used to obfuscade code even further

Comment: @StackDanny Yeah, it could be seen as unnecessarily obfuscating.

Comment: I knew that preprocessing was not always an automatic part of C compilation, but I didn't know that this was how the preprocessor was engaged.  Nice.